# Extension of an arithmetic function like Gamma function

Tags: number-theory, gamma-function

As you know Gamma function is an extension of the factorial function. Is there any other function which is the extension of an arithmetic function? For example extension of the Euler's totient function?

Comment: The monomial functions $f(n)=n^k$ are completely multiplicative arithmetic funcitons and can be extended to entire functions :)

Comment: Hmm... True... But i was asking about -i know my word choice is wrong- unusual arithmetic functions... Like Euler's totient function, Prime Counting function, möbius function etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as the [prime counting function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function) is concerned, we have the well-known asymptotics $\pi(x)\simeq$ $\dfrac x{\ln x}$ , which can indeed work as an ‘extension’, albeit the values are approximate, not exact. I am unaware of any meaningful closed-form formula that gives the exact values for this function. Also, for [Euler's totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) we have $\varphi(x)\simeq\dfrac x{e^\gamma\ln\ln x}$ , with the same observations in place. But these probably resemble more [Stirling's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) than an *actual* interpolation.